# Routes requiring authentication in react

Tags: authentication, react.js, url-routing, jsx

I'm looking for a way to do some route protection with react-router-4. Looking at an example in the documentation, they create a Component which is rendered like this:

> ```
> <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected} />
> ```

and the privateRoute component:

> ```
> const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
>   <Route {...rest} render={props => (
>     fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
>       <Component {...props}/>
>     ) : (
>       <Redirect to={{
>         pathname: '/login',
>         state: { from: props.location }
>       }}/>
>     )
>   )}/>
> )
> ```

I don't really understand why I should want to pass the "Protected" component as a property and then have to take care of spreading all the ...props and ...rest.

Before I was reading this doc (and other example), I created the following code, which just nest the routes in another component which takes care of the authentication part.

Because my example (which seems to work perfectly well), looks way more simplistic, I must be missing something.

Are there any downsides on this approach?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Nav from './Nav';

// dummy
const Auth = {
  isAuthenticated: () => { return true; }
}

const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>
const SignIn = () => <h1>SignIn</h1>
const About = () => <h1>About</h1>
class PrivateOne extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return <h1>Private</h1>
  }
}
const PrivateTwo = () => <h1>PrivateTwo</h1>
const PrivateThree = () => <h1>PrivateThree</h1>
const NotFound = () => <h1>404</h1>

const Private = ({isAuthenticated, children}) => {
  return(
    isAuthenticated ? (
      <div>
        <h1>Private</h1>
        {children}
      </div>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/sign_in',
      }}/>
    )
  )
}

const App = () =>
  <div>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/sign_in" component={SignIn} />
          <Private isAuthenticated={Auth.isAuthenticated()}> {/* or some state later on */}
            <Route path="/private1" component={PrivateOne} />
            <Route path="/private2" component={PrivateTwo} />
            <Route path="/private3" component={PrivateThree} />
          </Private>
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </div>

export default App;
```